# Illegal repetition

Tags: java, string

```
String[] parts = pptValue.split("{");
```

In my `pptValue`:

```
pptValue = EnvWDI{env}{client}
```

My error:

```
Caught: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition
{
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition
{
    at java_lang_String$split.call(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: It's a split on a regex, as the docs state.

Comment: pptValue = "EnvWDI{env}{client}"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you need to escape the curly brace, as in `"\\{"`.

Take a look at the docs for [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), in the section about escaping characters. Behind the curtains, `split` uses `Pattern`.

Answer (score 4):

The character `{` has special meaning when used in a *regular expression*.

The string passed to `String.split` is parsed as a regular expression and you will have to escape characters with special meaning, e.g. `"\\{"`.

The **backslash character** is used for escaping special characters. As the `\` has special meaning by itself in strings it must also be escaped, hence the double backslash.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape `{` as it is used to quantify a repetition, try:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        
    String pptValue = "foo{bar";
    String[] parts = pptValue.split("\\{");
    System.out.println(parts.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++){
        System.out.println(parts[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: That should be double backslash :)

Comment: @GiovanniBotta sure, corrected. I just kicked it from my head and didn't test it.